# Stripe pay up front slider where customer can use the slider to indicate how much they're willing to pay up front = possible?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am new to developing and am wondering if it's possible us to adjust Stripe's subscription upsells (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/upsells) to make it so that a customer can use a slider to adjust the amount they're willing to pay up front.

As they increase the amount to pay up front, it could provide a greater and greater discount for the customer.

My thoughts were that this could be done if adding the upsells function multiple times to a slider that's custom coded, representing different amounts a customer can pay up front as they adjust the amount, and offering a different overall cost?

Cheers!

Comment: Stripe Checkout currently doesn't use a slider to allow the customer to adjust the amount the customer is willing to pay upfront. You can consider a tiered / volume based pricing model if you want the customer to pay less as they increase the quantity. I'd suggest reaching out to Stripe Support since this is more of a question about their product feature / offerings and they will be able to better advise you about it.

Comment: I see. I think we could have three payment options on cards showing to a customer that they could pick from on the prior page